# JPanel inside JScrollPane scrollbars not showing up

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, zooming, jscrollpane

I am currently trying to make it possible for a JPanel to be zoomed in. My idea is pretty much as follows :

I have a JPanel (custom with overriden paintComponent etc.) that I place inside my JScrollPane.

What I do to zoom in is to scale up my JPanel using the following code (overriding the paint method)

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    if (m_hasBeenScaled)
    {
        m_transform.scale(m_zoomValue, m_zoomValue);
        g2.setTransform(m_transform);
        m_transform = new AffineTransform();
    }

    super.paint(g);
}
```

This works well, however my JScrollPane doesn't display scrollbars as I scale to bigger dimensions. How do I make the JScrollPane respond to this scale up of my JPanel ?

Here's the code I use to create both my JPanel and JScrollPan (Grid is my class extending JPanel):

```
m_gridPanel = new Grid();
m_gridContainer = new JScrollPane(m_gridPanel);
m_gridContainer.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(605, 605));
```

Comment: 1) See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.) 2) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 3) I'd approach this the same way as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27119520/418556)..

Comment: This `m_gridContainer.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(605, 605));` is a bad idea, the size of the component will change based on the zoom factor as well. Zooming a component is much more complex than changing the transform, you should be translating the mouse events as well, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21174997/how-to-add-mouselistener-to-item-on-java-swing-canvas/21175125#21175125 for example...

Comment: I am now overriding the getPreferredSize method as you said, and I now see the scrollbars appearing. However, when I slide them, the view doesn't change at all. Any reason for that ?

Answer (score 1):

The size of the component will be affected by the zoom factor as well, to that end, setting the `preferredSize` to a "static" value makes no sense, instead, you should be overriding the `getPreferredSize` and adjusting the size returned by applying the zoom factor to it as well.

Zooming a component is much more complex than changing the transform, you should be translating the mouse events as well, see [How to add MouseListener to item on Java Swing Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21174997/how-to-add-mouselistener-to-item-on-java-swing-canvas/21175125#21175125) for example.

Comment: I am now overriding the getPreferredSize method as you said, and I now see the scrollbars appearing. However, when I slide them, the view doesn't change at all. Any reason for that ?

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses